# "GO" button on mobile devices textarea

Tags: html, forms, mobile, submit

I want to add a GO button when users are typing text in a textarea on my site. On an `<input>` element this button appears when the input field is in a form and there is a submit button ( at least for my version of android that is ), however I can't get it to appear on a textarea.

What properties or elements do I need to set up so that I have a "GO" or "SUBMIT" button on mobile devices' virtual keyboards when typing in a textarea?

And a little visual, I'm talking about this guy in blue

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Add below lines to your EditText, Go Button will appear on your keypad

```
<EditText
android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
```

Use below code to listen `GO` button

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
            //perfrom your action
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks but this question is not scoped to android, but web development.